# How can i optimize this code to save execution time?

Tags: java

The code is the following. I think the sorting method takes more time.
so please modify the code if necessary.
The first line of the input contains two space-separated integers, N (the number of characters in the string) and Q (total number of queries), respectively.

The second line of the input contains the string S.

Each of the next Q lines contains a query . The query is one of the following two types:

- 1 X C -the query is of type 1, the character at the position X (integer) in the string should be replaced by C (character).
- 2 X -the query is of type 2, print out the character which would be present at the position X (integer) in the string if the characters in the string were arranged alphabetically.

OUTPUT:

For every query of type 2 print the character present at the position X if the characters in the string were arranged in the alphabetical order.

```
import java.util.*;

public class test{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);

        int N=scan.nextInt();
        int n=scan.nextInt();
        String S=scan.next();
        char[]chars=S.toCharArray();
        Arrays.sort(chars);

        StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder(S);

        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){

            int b=scan.nextInt();
            if(b==1){
                int c=scan.nextInt();
                char c1=scan.next().charAt(0);
                sb.setCharAt(c-1, c1);
                String newString=sb.toString();
                chars=newString.toCharArray();
                Arrays.sort(chars);
            }

            if (b==2){

                int c=scan.nextInt();
                System.out.println(chars[c-1]);
            }

        }
```

Comment: I think this belongs on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) since the code already works

Comment: Can you describe briefly what you are trying to achieve and the expected input and output?

Comment: Why are you trying to optimize compilation time?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question best suitable for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: i want to know if any other better method exists which will take less time for even very larger input.

Comment: Let me guess, when you say “compilation time” you really mean how long time the program runs? (I have heard about time complexity and space complexity before, but optimizing compilation time is new to me)

Comment: yeah.time complexity.that's what i am talking about

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to reduce the runtime.  You only need to hold two copies of the initial text, currently you have a `String` a `StringBuilder` and a `char[]`.  I would suggest that you only keep two of those: a `char[]` with the original order as modified by type 1 queries and a second `char[]` with the sorted characters for answering type 2 queries.

You sort the characters after every type 1 query.  That may not be necessary.  You only need to resort the sorted array when a type 2 query follows a type 1 query (or comes first).  Otherwise the sort is wasted.  That will save you some sorts, unless you are sure that every type 2 always follows a type 1.  The sort is certainly wasted if two or more type 1s follow each other.